# Java 8 - program not reading file but seems to be writing though

Tags: java, file-io

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.OpenOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class RAFRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create();
        read();
    }

    public static void create() {
        // Create the set of options for appending to the file.
        Set<OpenOption> options = new HashSet<OpenOption>();
        options.add(StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        options.add(StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        // Create the custom permissions attribute.
        Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions
                .fromString("rw-r-----");
        FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr = PosixFilePermissions
                .asFileAttribute(perms);
        Path file = Paths.get("./outfile.log");
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        try {
            SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(file, options, attr);
            for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i) {
                sbc = sbc.position(i * 4);
                buffer.clear();
                buffer.put(new Integer(i).byteValue());
                buffer.flip();
                sbc.write(buffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void read() {     
        // Create the set of options for appending to the file.
        Set<OpenOption> options = new HashSet<OpenOption>();
        options.add(StandardOpenOption.READ);
        Path file = Paths.get("./outfile.log");
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        try {
            SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(file, options);
            int nread;
            do {
                nread = sbc.read(buffer);
                if(nread!= -1) {
                    buffer.flip();
                    System.out.println(buffer.getInt());
                }
            } while(nread != -1 && buffer.hasRemaining());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I first create the file.
I am trying to put 9, then 8, then 7 and so on in the file.
But I am trying to add to file in reverse order using random access.
The output of file actually will be numbers in ascending order.
I am just writing to file in reverse order to try out random access writing.
After that I try to read the file and print the data (numbers).
It prints only 0. I was expecting it to print 1-9.
I couldn't figure out the reason. Any help is appreciated.


I followed this link from Oracle site: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

The file has size after I run this program, so it seems program is writing.
Since it is buffer read, i can't see the data by vi or cat.

Comment: Your code doesn't mention `RandomAccessFile` as far as I can tell... only your title and your tag do.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. In the statement sbc = sbc.position(i * 4); it should be going to a location/position and then write. And then since i reduces, it reverses, which is writing in random access. What is missing?

Comment: @cg `RandomAccessFile` is a Java class that you're not using, even though your title claims that you are. Even the name is correctly camel cased, so you can understand the confusion when your code example has nothing to do with [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Comment: I understand your point. I will remove the random access tag from the post. But why is this program not working, any idea?

Comment: Define 'crashed'. Silent exit? Error message? Exception? Core dump? Computer explodes?

Comment: @EJP. It throws Exception. I have already added the exception in the post towards the end. Please scroll below in the code section to see the detail exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `flip()` the buffer before calling `write()` or `get()`(and friends), and `compact()` afterwards.

Comment: I added flip() before write() and also after read(). The program is not throwing exception now. But prints only 0.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `flip()` after `read()`, and I'm not even slightly interested in what happens if you don't follow my answer entirely. But you could always try closing the file after writing it.

Comment: with flip() added to just before write and not any other place in code, the program throws exception as before. Since I removed the exception from the main question, pasting here for reference: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
 at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
 at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:361)
 at org.java.RAFRead.read(RAFRead.java:43)
 at org.java.RAFRead.main(RAFRead.java:23)